# meshlab v2020.07 won't open/import ply file on Mac

Tags: meshlab

The error message is

Error details: file format ply not supported.

I have tried to search for an answer but could not find one. Plugins don't seem to exist either.

Comment: This seems more a bug than a request of help. Probably opening an issue on the github tracking site ( https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues/new ) with all the detailed information needed

Comment: Did just that, thanks for the tip.